# Post facebook status from android app having smiley signs and links to various pages/events

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want the user to post a prestored status on their wall
e.g is attending "page/event name(facebook page)" at "place name(facebook page)"

I want that wall post dialog box just as it is in facebook app with that prestored  message on the wall post screen.

Currently I am posting the wall post without any prestored message.

I have tried using  `parameters.putString` but isnt helping me out